# Should [gdiplus] be a synonym of [gdi+]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Should the [gdiplus](/questions/tagged/gdiplus) tag on Stack Overflow be a synonym of the [gdi+](/questions/tagged/gdi%2b) tag or the other way round?

- [gdi+](/questions/tagged/gdi%2b) 869 questions.
- [gdiplus](/questions/tagged/gdiplus) 26 questions.

Comment: Several had both, but I went ahead and renamed the `gdiplus` ones to `gdi+` (or removed the dupes in favor of `gdi+`) so whatever is the correct parent could then be easily applied.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I believe they should be combined. `gdiplus` is more searchable, and Microsoft uses it in some of their function names - I would prefer it to `gdi+` even though it seems less popular.