# Why does [google+] map to [google-plus] rather than the other way around?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

I just came across the [google-plus](/questions/tagged/google-plus) tag. Now, being one of those who can't stand little things like people writing "Google Plus" rather than the official branding "Google+" (yes, I'm way too anal about official brand and trademark usage), I was wondering if there was a [google+](/questions/tagged/google%2b) tag.

Sure enough, there is. They are linked synonymously as well, so that's great. Except I have another question: why does [google+](/questions/tagged/google%2b) get mapped to [google-plus](/questions/tagged/google-plus) rather than the other way around, since Google+ is the official "spelling"? After all, [cpp](/questions/tagged/cpp) maps to [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) rather than both mapping to something like [c-plus-plus](/questions/tagged/c-plus-plus)...

Comment: Perhaps this is simply because the [tag:google-plus] tag was created first?

Comment: I'm waiting to see if there's an actual technical reason for this before reversing the synonym.

Comment: @Bill there's no technical reason tags can't end in `+` as shown by [c++] and an even more close example, [gdi+] - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gdi%2b

Comment: @Daniel DiPaolo: Ah, yes. You were the one who retagged [gdiplus] questions to [gdi+]. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96284/should-gdiplus-be-a-synonym-of-gdi

Comment: @BoltClock yes, my "put a + when you mean a +" agenda is going well!

Comment: @Daniel: I thought the [c++] tag caused problems in search and they had to make it a special case.  If that's fixed (or was just my imagination) then there's no reason [google+] can't be the official tag.

Comment: @Bill: Indeed, if you enter "google+" in the search form now, the + isn't taken into account. However if you made it the official tag, I bet the system will convert that into a tag search, and return questions with the [google+] tag (like it currently does for [c++]).

Comment: The only hitch is future compound tags.  See [Clicking google+-api tag results in a tag search for google -api](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97438/clicking-google-api-tag-results-in-a-tag-search-for-google-api).

Comment: Isn't C++ special cased and reason why other tags don't need it because then you'll have to try and catch all future + uses?